# Notepad++ Bookmark lines along document map?

Tags: notepad++

While working in Notepad++ I have the document map open. With long files i'd love to be able to place a bookmark along the scrollbar or near the document map so I can quickly jump to sections of code. Ideally the bookmark would have a small notation so I can see or hover over the bookmark and see what the code is

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the existing bookmark feature?  Ctrl-F2 will toggle a bookmark, and F2/shift-F2 will navigate forward/backwards among the bookmarks.  This doesn't get you the scroll bar indicator or preview on hover . . .

Comment: @Ernie yes i've used the default bookmark features, i was looking for a way to annotate the bookmarks